# Can't save text file with BOM in UTF-8 encoding

Tags: c#, formatting

Weird issue, i found a lot of solutions but none of them seems to work.
This is my code at this moment and i allways getting UTF-8 without BOM, but in my case i want BOM.

```
[...]

MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream, new UTF8Encoding(true));
streamWriter.Write(convertedFile);
streamWriter.Flush();
memoryStream.Position = 0;

string[] fileNameParts = entry.FullName.Split('.');
ZipArchiveEntry newZipArchiveEntry = newArchive.CreateEntry(fileNameParts[0] + "." + fileNameParts[1] + destinationFileExtension);

using (var openNewArchiveEntry = newZipArchiveEntry.Open())
{
    memoryStream.CopyTo(openNewArchiveEntry);
}

[...]
```

Comment: Why do you assume there's no BOM? How do you check for its existence? What does `convertedFile` contain? What is `convertedFile`? Unless it's a string or character, that code will. call `.ToString()` on the object and write the result.

Comment: When i open file with BOM i see in notepad on the bottom UTF-8 with BOM, but when i open file from my app, there is UTF-8 only.

Comment: So the file *does* have a BOM. A [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) is only a few bytes at the start of the file that specify the encoding. They never appear in the text itself. The contents are the same, whether a BOM exists or not

Comment: BTW instead of writing to a MemoryStream you could write directly to the entry's stream, `openNewArchiveEntry`, eg `using var sw=new StreamWriter(openNewArchiveEntry,new UTF8Encoding(true));sw.Write(someString);`

Comment: Nothing works, always without BOM

Comment: How did you determine there's no BOM? You still haven't posted something that shows there's a real problem. To demonstrate an actual problem all you'd need is a `StreamWriter` opened over a new file, and check whether it's missing by reading the first 3 bytes afterwards. [The source does write the BOM though](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/8538436d2820bd1610a52801eaf4c983e8fba188/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/StreamWriter.cs#L291)

Comment: In fact, you can check the MemoryStream's first 3 bytes right away. What do they contain?